# Where does $\int_0^1 \frac{e^{xy}-1}{y}dy$ converge

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

The question is for what $x$ does it converge?

My try:

$$\int_0^1 \frac{e^{xy}-1}{y}dy = \int_0^1e^{xy}y^{-1} - \int_0^1 y^{-1} dy = \infty +...$$

Does that mean it doesn't converge for any $x$, since $\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}\ln(y) = -\infty$.

In solutions it says otherwise.

EDIT:

$$\lim_{y\rightarrow 0} \frac{e^{xy}-1}{y} = \infty$$
$$\lim_{y\rightarrow 1} \frac{e^{xy}-1}{y}  = e^x-1$$

Comment: If you break it into two infinite parts, you cannot proceed beyond that point. What you need to do instead is analyse *why* this function may possibly not be integrable. Clearly it's continuous except possibly at the endpoints, so the only problems are at the endpoints. Thus, it would make sense to compute $\lim_{y \to 1} \frac{e^{xy}-1}{y}$ and $\lim_{y \to 0} \frac{e^{xy}-1}{y}$. Finding these quantities will help you argue convergence/divergence of the integral using comparison principles with the limits. So edit your question with the limit values.

Comment: It converges for $x=0$.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer I edited

Comment: @VLC Your first limit is wrong. In fact, what is true is that the limit $\lim_{y \to 0} \frac{e^{xy}-1}{y} = x$. Check this once again. When you have done that, you know that the left and right endpoints are *not* a problem, because you can do this : take the integral $\int_0^1$ and break it into three parts : $\int_0^{\delta}, \int_{\delta}^{1-\delta}, \int_{1-\delta}^1$ for a small $\delta$. Now, compare the first part with $\int_0^{\delta} xdy$. Compare the third with $\int_{1-\delta}^1 (e^x-1)dy$. For the second, use the fact that a continuous function on a compact interval is bounded.

Comment: For the comparisons, use the definition of those limits you found to get a suitable $\delta$, and follow it up with the comparison test. This is a very , very commonly occurring situation in integral convergence.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer What is the "first part", to compare it with $\int_0^{\delta}xdy$

Comment: Compare $\int_0^\delta \frac{e^{xy}-1}{x} dy$  with $\int_0^\delta xdy$. Use the fact that $\lim_{y \to 0} \frac{\frac{e^{xy}-1}{y}}{x}=1$.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer Ok, so if I understand correctly, I have to use the majorant theorem here that if $g<f$ and $f$ is convergent (in this case $x\cdot \delta$ and $(e^x-1)\cdot \delta$ are convergent) I get the result that on the interval $[0,\delta]$ and $[1-\delta, 1]$ the integral converges ?

Comment: Exactly , perfect. Now, in the middle interval $[\delta,1-\delta]$ the function $\frac{e^{xy}-1}{y}$ is continuous, hence bounded. So you can use the majorant theorem again. The advantage of this approach is how generally it can be applied in various situations regarding integral convergence.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer I see, so generally there could be an interval where the integral is divergent and we can "mark" it with $\delta$.

Comment: Exactly. The role of the $\delta$s is to separate the function into "nice" and "not nice" parts, where basically the nice parts are convergent for obvious reasons and the "not nice" parts require comparison arguments. The point is, if even one comparison fails, you know that the integral is divergent. If all comparisons go through, then you know that the integral is convergent. *Usually*, when you receive exercises of this kind, you should be be adept at isolating these "not nice" parts and finding out how the function behaves there. Even more commonly ,the "not nice" parts are the ends.

Comment: Of course, this doesn't work all the time, especially when the nice and not nice parts aren't easy to work with. But as exercises appearing in a book or for a first course, you expect this to be the standard way to solve such a question.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer So for the comparison between $g<f$ I could also differentiate the functions and see if maybe there is a maximum in between the intervals, not exaclty at the endpoints? Does the comparison of two functions mean the comparison of their supremums/maximums, or the function overall?

Comment: Comparison refers to comparison overall. If you want to say that $\int f \leq\int g$ you will need $f(x)\leq g(x)$ on every point in the domain you're integrating $f,g$ over. That can be proved using differentiation etc. , but usually what you want to prove for integral comparison is that $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ is bounded on either side by constants in that domain. If such an inequality is true, then, $\int f, \int g$ are "the same" level of nice or not nice, when it comes to checking convergence, so you can interchange $f$ with $g$ on that domain if you're just checking convergence.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer Because I don't know how to solve the inequality $\frac{e^{xy}-1}{y} < \delta \cdot x$, that the result would be that the inequality holds for all $x$. Also how do you know what part of the function bellow the integral to put into the bounds from $1$ to $\delta$ and then from $\delta$ to $1-\delta$ and so on ?

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer My try would be: $$\frac{e^{xy}-1-\delta xy}{y}<0$$

If $y<0$

$$e^{xy}<\delta xy + 1$$

now because delta is small, we can say that 

$$e^{xy}<1$$

and we solve for that.

And then we also do for $y \geq 0$

Comment: @VLC Thanks a lot for your efforts, I've added a +1 to your question, and since I haven't quite been able to communicate my idea using the comments which is somewhat unfortunate, I'll write an answer instead. I will request some time for this purpose.

Answer (score 4):

Termwise integration of the integrand expanded as a Taylor series in $y$ gives
$$\int_0^1\frac{e^{xy}-1}y\,dy=\int_0^1\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^ny^{n-1}}{n!}\,dy=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_0^1\frac{x^ny^{n-1}}{n!}\,dy=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n\cdot n!}$$
which clearly converges everywhere by (e.g.) the ratio test.

Answer (score 4):

Note that

$$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{e^t-1}{t} = e^0 = 1$$

For $x=0$ nothing is to show. For fixed $x\neq 0$ you get

$$\int_0^1\frac{e^{xy}-1}{y}dy = x \int_0^1\frac{e^{xy}-1}{xy}dy$$

where $\frac{e^{xy}-1}{xy}$ is continuous for $y \in (0,1]$ and can be continuously extended into $y=0$. Hence the integral converges for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a "general" procedure for testing convergence of the integral of some function on an interval.

So let's say you have, $\int_a^b f_x(y)dy$. That is, $y$ is varying between $a$ and $b$, and $x$ is an external parameter which affects the function $f$. What you want to do, is analyse for what values of $x$ does $\int_a^b f_x(y)dy$ exist. Potentially, $a,b$ can be (positive/negative) infinity as well.

---

Usually, two common theorems are used for the purpose of testing convergence, at least in the beginning. I'll state them.

- $\textrm{Convergence for bounded functions}$ : On a closed and bounded interval $[a,b]$, any bounded function $f_x$ has a bounded integral $\int_a^b f_x(y)dy$. Furthermore , if $f_x$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ then it is bounded on $[a,b]$ and hence has a bounded integral on this interval.
- $\textrm{Equivalence/Comparison Principle}$ : Let $f,g$ be two functions on an interval (possibly unbounded, can be open or closed on either side) $[a,b]$ with the following property : there exist constants $C_1,C_2>0$ such that $C_1 f(x) \leq g(x) \leq C_2f(x)$ for $x \in [a,b]$. Then, $\int_a^b f(x)dx$ exists, *if and only if* $\int_a^b g(x)dx$ exists.
- $\textrm{Break-up Principle}$ : Suppose $[a,b]$ is broken into various subintervals $[a_1,b_1],...,[a_n,b_n]$ such that $\int_{a_i}^{b_i} f_x(y)dy$ is finite on each of these subintervals. Then, $\int_a^b f_x(y)dy$ exists. On the other hand, if even one of the integrals is infinite or doesn't exist, then $\int_a^b f_x(y)dy$ does not converge.

---

Therefore, suppose you have an integral like $\int_a^b f_x(y)dy$ whose convergence you'd like to test, you should ideally see if one can use the principles mentioned above to test convergence.

I outline the following strategy for this purpose. This strategy works for most elementary questions, but *NOT* in general. If I had to be more precise : this doesn't work when the integral is "oscillatory" in nature and the integral is kind of moving up and down without converging. In those cases, more care is required.

- Let the interval be $[a,b]$ and suppose you're studying the convergence of $\int_a^b g(x)dx$.
- Find the points in $(a,b)$ where $g$ is "infinite" i.e. points $d$ that $\lim_{x \to d} g(x)$ is $\pm \infty$. Put these points together to create a set $S$ of "problem points". To $S$, add the set of endpoints $[a,b]$ (add $d = \pm \infty$ if they are any of the endpoints).
- At each point $d$ in $S$, find suitable functions $h_d(x)$ defined in a locality of $d$ (so for $d=\infty$, find a function defined on $[j,\infty)$ for $j$ large enough) so that $\lim_{x \to d} \frac{g(x)}{h_d(x)}$ is a finite non-zero number.
- Check if, for each $d$ in $S$, the integral of $h_d(x)$ exists over the neighbourhood on which $h_d$ is defined. If it *does* for every $d$, then the integral $\int_a^b g(x)dx$ *is convergent*. If even one case fails, then $\int_a^b g(x)dx$ is *not convergent*.
- An additional, *fine* points in the strategy : if , at a problem point $d$, $\lim_{x \to d} g(x)$ exists, then $h_d = 1$ can be taken.

---

We will use this to solve :

$$
\int_0^1 \frac{e^{xy}-1}{y}dy \quad ; \quad f_x(y) = \frac{e^{xy}-1}{y}
$$

We have to check the convergence of this integral for various fixed values of $x$. Remove the trivial case $x=0$ first : in this case, the function is just the zero function. That is, $x \neq 0$ from now on.

We have a huge advantage in this case (and in a *lot* of cases): on $(0,1)$, the function $f_x(y)$ is *continuous*, because it's a quotient of continuous functions on this interval. Therefore the "problem" points in this case are the endpoints, $0$ and $1$. From now on, I attempt to follow the strategy : but *not rigorously, only roughly*. We will be rigorous later on.

Take the problem point $d=1$. We observe that $$
\lim_{t \to 1} f_x(t) = e^x-1
$$

therefore, we take the function $h_1 =1$ in a neighbourhood of $1$. Now, at the problem point $0$,
$$
\lim_{t \to 1} f_x(t) = \lim_{t \to 1} \frac{e^{xt}-1}{t} = x
$$

Therefore, as $x$ is fixed and finite, we take $h_0 = 1$ here as well.

The appropriate neighbourhoods of $0$ and $1$ will be , well, $(-\delta,\delta)$ and $(1-\delta,1+\delta)$ for small enough $\delta$. Are $h_0,h_1$ integrable over their respective intervals? I mean, obviously, right?

Therefore, *following the strategy*, we expect *convergence for all values of $x$*. Now, let's be rigorous.

---

##### Rigorous proof

Let us collect the facts from the above exploration that we will need. *We will assume that $x$ is positive : I leave the proof for $x$ negative as an exercise*. The proof for $x$ negative will involve changing the order of some inequalities below, but nothing more than that. The idea remains the same.

1. $f_x(y)$ is continuous on $(0,1)$.
2. $\lim_{t \to 0} f_x(t) = x$.
3. $\lim_{t\to 1} f_x(t) = e^x-1$.

Now, we will make the following *rigorous conclusions*. Watch how we do this : the same argument will recur many times.

4. Since $\lim_{t \to 0} f_x(t) = x$, by the quotient rule we know that $\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{f_x(t)}{x} = 1$, and there exists a $\delta_1>0$ small enough such that for $0\leq x<\delta_1$ , $0.5 \leq \frac{f_x(t)}{x} \leq 1.5$.
5. Since $\lim_{t \to 1} f_x(t) = e^x-1$, by the quotient rule we know that $\lim_{t \to 1}{f_x(t)}{e^x-1} = 1$. Therefore, there exists a $\delta_2>0$ small enough such that for $1-\delta_2<x\leq 1$, $0.5 \leq \frac{f_x(t)}{e^x-1} \leq 1.5$.
6. Since $f_x(t)$ is continuous on $[\delta_1,1-\delta_2]$, it is bounded. Say the constant bounding it is $M$.

We now perform the following break-up.
$$
\int_0^1 f_x(t)dx = \int_0^{\delta_1} f_x(t)dx + \int_{\delta_1}^{1-\delta_2} f_x(t)dt + \int_{1-\delta_2}^1 f_x(t)dt
$$

Let's deal with each of the parts now : by point 4., we have $$
0.5x\delta_1 =0.5\int_0^{\delta_1} xdt \leq  \int_0^{\delta_1} f_x(t)dt \leq 1.5 \int_0^{\delta_1} xdt = 1.5x\delta_1
$$

By point 6., we have :$$
-(1-\delta_2-\delta_1)M = \int_{\delta_1}^{1-\delta_2} (-M)dt \leq \int_{\delta_1}^{1-\delta_2} f_x(t)dt \leq \int_{\delta_1}^{1-\delta_2} Mdt = (1-\delta_2-\delta_1)M
$$

By point 5., we have :
$$
0.5(e^x-1)\delta_2 =0.5\int_{1-\delta_2}^{1} (e^x-1)dt \leq  \int_{1-\delta_2}^{1} f_x(t)dt \leq 1.5 \int_{1-\delta_2}^{1} (e^x-1)dt = 1.5(e^x-1)\delta_2
$$

Combining the three identities above and using the break-up, we obtain : $$
0.5x\delta_1 +(-(1-\delta_2-\delta_1)M)+0.5(e^x-1)\delta_2 \\ \leq \int_0^1 f_x(t)dt \\ \leq 1.5x\delta_0 +((1-\delta_2-\delta_1)M)+1.5(e^x-1)
\delta_2
$$

which proves that the integral exists for *all* values of $x$.